# How to strip "()," from Python, PyODBC, SQL Returns?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I grabbed a bunch of SQL IDs I need to update with Python and PyODBC:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=YesOne;PWD=xxx')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM One.dbo.Two WHERE STATUS = 'OnGoing' AND ID = ''")
```

I have a second bit of code that updates the IDs:

```
cursor.execute("Update One.dbo.Two SET STATUS = 'Completed', Modified = 'Today' WHERE ID = '1051'")
```

The problem is when I view the IDs grabbed in Python earlier I get either:

```
row = cursor.fetchall()
f row:
    print row
```

> [(1016, ), (1017, ), (1019, ), (1020,
>   ), (1021, ), (1025, ), (1026, ),
>   (1027, ), (1029, ), (1048, ), (1049,
>   )]

or

```
if row:
    print row[3]
```

> (1020, )

I need just the number so I can run my second part of the script for the:

```
WHERE ID = '1051'"
```

part. I tried with:

```
count = len(row)
while count > 0:
    newrow = row[count-1]
    print 'SELECT ID FROM One.dbo.Two WHERE ID = ' + str(newrow)
    count = count-1
```

and it gave me:

> SELECT ID FROM One.dbo.Two WHERE ID = (1049, )
>   SELECT ID FROM One.dbo.Two WHERE ID = (1048, )
>   etc...

And I tried:

```
str(row[1]).lstrip('(),')
```

and I got:

> '1017, )'

How do I strip the characters from the ID so I can reuse the ID?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all:

```
rows = [x[0] for x in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Then abandon your terrible while loop:

```
for row in rows:
  print 'SELECT ID FROM One.dbo.Two WHERE ID = %s' % row
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you are accessing a tuple from within a list, so need to specify location in list and location in tuple:

```
row = cursor.fetchall()
f row:
    print row
    print row[3]
    print row[3][0]
```

outputs:

```
[(1016, ), (1017, ), (1019, ), (1020, ), (1021, )]
(1020, )
1020
```